# dependencies/AndroidManifest error

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I compiled a source code which made by colleague. But I got a few error messages.

At first, AndroidManifest error.

The address is

"app/build/intermediates/instant-run-support/debug/dependencies/AndroidManifest.xml"

And the message is "resource string/app_version not found."

Actually, "app_version" is declared on string. And if I delete or modify the AndroidManifest file, it is created or recover automatically. So I cannot delete or modify.

This is AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="asdasd"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.5.1.0">


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="false">
    </activity>
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".UartService"
        android:exported="false" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

And this is dependencies/AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="passtech.mobilelocker"
  android:versionCode="4"
  android:versionName="@string/app_version"
  split="lib_dependencies_apk">
</manifest>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you modify/delete any file under /build/* the next time it will be regenerated exactly as the previous time because you're not modifying the original one. You should update /src/*

Comment: you try clean then build again. Please show more code file Manifest

Comment: @quangminhs I added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try remove version code and version name on file manifest. Then add version code, version name on app build file like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ifs.vpbs"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Wow! The way which you told solve the problem! The problem is versionName on app. It has not "". So it makes error. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

under this path "app/build/" every file generated automatically .
modify origin AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: then how can I fix that? what does that mean "clean"? It means Build - Clean project? I already did.

Comment: on origin AndroidManifest code, "string/app_version" is not matter. it goes well.